# How to know whether microphone is in use or not in Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, microphone

I want to know whether the microphone of my phone is in use or not?
How can it be done through Android NDK....
I am a newbie so don't have much idea regarding this.....

Comment: What do you mean "is in use"? Do you mean, is it picking up sound? Or is it enabled? Or is it present in the device?

Comment: @Eric By "in use" i mean it is picking sound

Comment: A wild guess here, and I'm not an expert with the NDK. But I'd guess you have to use the [OpenSL](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/ndk/r5/opensles/) library, and check if the recorded input has a certain decibel level.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the suggestion...but it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to determine if another application is currently using the microphone.